# ajax status code returns 0 when fiddler detects 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing quite a few jquery ajax calls and I wanted to catch the 401 status code on all of them. So, I'm using $.ajaxSetup() to catch every call that gets a 401 and redirect to the login page. It looks like this,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields : {withCredentials : true},
    crossDomain : true,
    complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log("Default Test");
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        if(jqXHR.status == 401){
            console.log("True");
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        }else if(jqXHR.status == 423){
            console.log("False");
            window.location.href = "gateway.html";
        }
    }
});
```

I make a call that is unauthorized. When looking at it in fiddler, I get a 401 status. When I pull up the console in chrome, it also says that I got a 401 status. But, if I look at the jqXHR.status, it says it got 0 as a status. And text status only says, "error". Not very helpful. I've tested this in chrome, FF and IE. They all do the same thing.

Any idea how I can get it to show 401? I don't want to just do a,

```
if(jqXHR.status == 0){
    window.location.href = "login.html";
}
```

Because I'm pretty sure that the status code of 0 will come up on more than just unauthorized calls, and I don't want to be redirecting to login when that's not the problem.

An example of one of the ajax calls that's being made.

```
function getStats(){
        $.ajax({
            url: DONEP+'dashboard/stats/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                ...
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How is the Ajax call being made? What is triggering it? Button click, form submission, anchor, etc.

Comment: @epascarello function call on page load. I could show an example of one of them.

Comment: And you are running this on a webserver?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I am.

Comment: Is the server serving up the correct CORS headers on the page you are requesting? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure. I'm not in charge of that part.. Would there be a way to see from fiddler?

Comment: Look at the response headers, the link I posted shows example headers.

Comment: @epascarello The Access-Control-Allow- Credentials/Origin seem to be missing when I get a 401. but when I log in and do the call again, I get a 200 and the headers are there. That might just be my problem.

Comment: @epascarello It was the problem indeed. The headers weren't being set. Thanks for your help. I'll let you put it in an answer if you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)